# Where is Correlate Button to Configure Analytical Driver Correlation?

Tags: filter, parameters, correlation, spagobi, cockpit

It is really giving me a headache trying to figure out and find resources on how to Analytical Driver Correlation.

I am trying to follow the instruction from [Wiki Spagobi](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/AD_correlated), however, I can't find the configuration page where the correlate button is located.

My ultimate goal is to have a filter on my Cockpit report as mentioned on [Wiki Spagobi](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/AD_correlated) as an example:

"consider two geographical Analytical Driver 'continent' and 'state', if you associate both to a business document probably you want that if a user choose a continent then the state Analytical Driver shows only the states of the continent selected."

Any information, suggestion, advice, direction will be greatly appreciated!

J

Answer (score 0):

Actually in SpagoBI 5.2, which is what i'm using, you manage correlation of two analytical drivers in the "Document detail" of the document that you want to make this.

[highlighted button of correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIE44.png)